# php-fpm -t error failed to open access log (log/access.log): No such file or directory (2)

Tags: logging, php

while modify file `etc/php-fpm.conf`, if I open the option `access.log = log/access.log`, then php-fpm will test error.

```
➜  sbin  ./php-fpm -t

[26-May-2014 17:44:05] ERROR: failed to open access log (log/access.log): No such file or directory (2)

[26-May-2014 17:44:05] ERROR: failed to post process the configuration

[26-May-2014 17:44:05] ERROR: FPM initialization failed
```

I wonder it is I didn't set correct user and group, or other.

PS.

the error_log write success in var/log/php-fpm.log.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have the impression you did not understand the difference between absolute and relative paths!

The file you modified probably is `/etc/php-fpm.conf`, not `etc/php-fpm.conf`. Note the leading slash (`/`), that makes a *huge* difference. The same things probably raises your issue: where is `log/access.log` meant to be located inside the file system? Relative to the processes working directory? Relative to the starting directory of the php interpreter? Where is that? You probably want to use `/log/access.log` instead if a folder `/log` exists (typical would be `/var/log` actually, but that depends on your system and setup). Again: note the leading slash!

Comment: Thanks. I know i edit the file etc/php-fpm.conf. that's correct. the question is I found 'log/access.log' is relative path, but the prefix I didn't know.

Comment: Sorry, I can't really follow you here. Again you confuse relative and absolute paths, I have the impression. Besides, `access.log` defines which log file to use. It only has to exist and be writable. `touch` and check its permissions.

Comment: enn. I found log/access.log default relative which I execute php-fpm. for example, when I run ./php-fpm -t in php-fpm/sbin/ path, it will run error.  but run ./sbin/php-fpm -t in php-fpm/ path, it success...

Comment: All in all, thanks for your answers leading me to find the path problem.

Comment: I have to repeat: you did not understand what relative and absolute paths are and how they work. Looks like you _think_ you do, but your replies do not really make sense.